# catkin_make opencv version conflict

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-melodic, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone ;
When I write catkin_make it gives such a warning.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.4.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.2.0, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.3.2.
```

I installed opencv with sudo apt and then I installed it from source. How can i fix the warning ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344695/catkin_make-opencv-version-conflict./) by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the CMAKE lists txt file you can specify the version your package should use.

In find_package() command specify the version you need:

find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)

---

Originally posted by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) with karma: 61 on 2020-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on 2020-02-20**:
Normally this was the case;

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS

  rospy

  roscpp

  OpenCV

  message_filters

)
```

When I type OpenCV 4.2.0 , I get an error.(catkin_make error)

**Comment by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) on 2020-02-20**:
add a separate find_package() underneath not as a COMPONENT. Makesure your cmake modules path is set

**Comment by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on 2020-02-25**:
Like this ?

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS

  cv_bridge

  message_filters

  roscpp

  rospy

  sensor_msgs

  std_msgs

)

find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)
```

**Comment by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on 2020-02-27**:
I get the same warning again.

**Comment by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on 2020-02-27**:
How Ros finds OpenCV 3.2. I didn't even write it in the CMakeList.

**Comment by [wgengland](https://answers.ros.org/users/52825/wgengland/) on 2020-03-24**:
I' wondering this too.. but in windows!

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-03-08**:
@jahim44229 I'm facing now the same warning. I'm using opencv 4.5.1 but I found out that cv_bridge recommended version for ros melodic is the 3.2. Check [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023). Maybe that is why ROS finds 3.2 directly. I'm trying to make my node work fully with 3.2